# Rails 3: How to add user_id - current_user.id assotiations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this part of code:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#generating-a-controller

But I have one more column "user_id" in my comment table. How can I assotiate user_id with current_user.id?

ps. I have working example in my app:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
@post.user_id = current_user.id
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say something like this.

```
@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
@comment.user_id = current_user.id
@comment.save
```

you could put the user_id in the params but that wouldnt be safe. user_id shouldnt be in 'attr_accessable' so it will be protected for mass_assignment.

You could do the above in a one liner but personally i dont like that. I think like this, it is more clear. If you want to have error handling you could do the save like this.

```
if @comment.save
  # success
else
  # error
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].merge(:user => current_user))
```

Comment: I dont like this approach because user_id shouldnt be in attr_accessable so mass_assignment shouldnt be allowed in my opinion. If they inject right now with another user id it will be save because it will overwrite it but still it shouldnt be because of mass assignment.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but how it said Michael, in this case user_id may be in attr_accessable.