# Why is the user_id suddenly not being assigned when I add more models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

These are my associations:

```
class User
 has_many :products
 has_many :prices
 has_many :businesses
 has_many :stores
end

class Price
 belongs_to :store
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :product
end

class Store
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :business
  has_many :prices
end

class Business
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :stores
end

class Product
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :prices
end
```

These are the changes I made so the associations work correctly:

1. All models have the user_id in their tables.
2. I put the associations inside like I have above.
3. I made CanCan abilities reflect these changes

   ```
   def initialize(user)
     if user.role == "admin"
       can :manage, :all
     elsif user.role == "default"
       can :manage, [Price, Store, Business, Product], :user_id => user.id
       can :read, [Product, Store, Business, Price]
     end
   end
   ```

I am using Devise if it helps to know.

When I want to create a Business, it lets me but their is no assigned user. I'm lost to what's the issue. I thought it would assign itself automatically like it was before when Users just had many prices. What do you think the problem is?

**EDIT**

---

```
class BusinessesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def show
    @business = Business.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @business = Business.new
  end

  def create
    @business = Business.new(params[:business])
    if @business.save
      redirect_to new_business_path, :notice => "Successfully added."
    else
      render :new, :notice => "It seems there was an error. Please try again."
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What code are you running to create a Business?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to create the business through the user or assign the user_id in the controller on save.

eg:  `current_user.businesses.create(params[:business])`  instead of `Business.create(params[:business])`

OR

```
Business.create(params[:business].merge(:user => current_user))
```

To make sure all your attributes are being passed in, use a validation along the lines of

```
validates_presence_of :user_id
```

on the models that have this data column

Comment: Maybe `current_user.businesses.create(params[:business])` and `Business.create(params[:business].merge(:user => current_user))`? Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128214/rails-3-how-to-add-user-id-current-user-id-assotiations

Comment: As mentioned in the post Mikhail D referenced, you should set the user in the controller instead of assigning it through the params. Otherwise someone can fake a request and pretend to be a random user.

Comment: but it has roles control via cancan ... so this shouldn't be an issue

Comment: @MikhailD thanks for that, updated and upvoted ...  , jagse, the roles are managed via cancan, is it still an issue?