# Strange Can't mass-assign protected attributes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Using Rails 3. By right, I am not supposed to need to declare the `attr_accessible :rating, :review, :user`, but if I don't, the review form would return the error `Can't mass-assign protected attributes error :rating, :review, :user`. I don't wanna to expose the entire `:user` because of security reason. What have I done wrong?

```
# review.rb

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reviewable, :polymorphic => true, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true

  attr_accessible :rating, :review, :user

  validates :review, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 2, :maximum => 500 }
  validates :rating, :inclusion => { :in => ApplicationConstants::RATINGS.collect(&:first) }  
end

# reviews_controller.rb

class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_reviewable

  def create
    @review = @reviewable.reviews.new(params[:review].merge(:user => current_user))
    if @review.save
      flash[:success] = 'Thanks for adding your review.'
      redirect_to @reviewable
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Error, try again.'
      redirect_to @reviewable
    end
  end

  ...

  private

  def find_reviewable
    resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
    @reviewable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
  end
end

# user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews, :as => :reviewable
end

# reviews/_form.html.erb

<%= form_for [@reviewable, @review] do |f| %>
  <div id="rating_buttons" class="btn-group" data-toggle-name="review[rating]" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <% ApplicationConstants::RATINGS.each do |rating| %>
      <button type="button" class="btn<%= active(@review.rating, rating[0]) %>" value="<%= rating[0] %>"><%= rating[1] %></button>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :rating %>
  <%= f.text_area :review, :class => 'input-xxlarge', :rows => '3' %><br>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to the this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128214/rails-3-how-to-add-user-id-current-user-id-assotiations), I fixed by issuing the following:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def create
    @review = @reviewable.reviews.new(params[:review])
    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    ...
  end
end
```

By doing this, the `user` model needs not be declared as mass-assignable.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the :rating and :review accessible. why do you need to make the user accessible? If you are simply trying to save a user's review (of course when he is signed in), then you can pass in the user's id from the controller which I see that you have done in the create method.

If there is something else you are trying to achieve, let me know.

Comment: Why do I even need to make :rating and :review accessible? In other models, I don't need to declare that. Same goes to user_id, because I have already merged it in the controller, I should not have the need to declare the user to be accessible. I don't want to declare these.

Comment: of course, I dont recommend that you allow the user_id to be mass assignable. You can save the current user into a variable say current_user and place the code in your application controller. Then you can do some like current_user.reviews.build(params[:review]) in the review controller which will automatically adds the user_id to your reviews table. But for review and ratings, you can simply make it accessible using attr_accessible like you have. Read the documentation here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible

Answer (score 0):

use [assign_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/assign_attributes)  to set all the attributes for a particular mass-assignment security role by passing in a hash of attributes

```
user = User.new
user.assign_attributes({ :name => 'Josh', :is_admin => true })
```